# При чтении файла считывает последнюю строку два раза, как этого избежать? c++

Tags: c++, ввод, fstream

```
string str, text;
openFile.open(fName);
while(openFile) {
    openFile >> str;
    text += str;
}
openFile.close();
```

Comment: Это уже классическая ошибка. Условие в `while(openFile)` станет `false` только *после* неудачного чтения, а не когда было прочитано последнее число.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что не проверяете успешность чтения...

```
while(openFile >> str) {
    text += str;
}
```